# Ansible add a line in file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add a new line in a file through the ansible *lineinfile* module. Below is the task defined in the playbook

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/httpd/file.conf
    line: myfilecontent
```

It works fine and add a new line in the file. But, when I modify the line content to some other value, e.g. 'mynewfilecontent', it adds another line instead of updating it

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/httpd/file.conf
    line: mynewfilecontent
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the *state* parameter of [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) module and create the below structure

```yaml
    my_lines:
      - line: myfilecontent
        state: absent
      - line: mynewfilecontent
        state: present
```

The *state* parameter controls if the line is present or absent in the file. See the example below

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost

      vars:

        my_lines:
          - line: myfilecontent
            state: absent
          - line: mynewfilecontent
            state: present

      tasks:

        - lineinfile:
            path: /tmp/test.conf
            create: yes
            line: "{{ item.line }}"
            state: "{{ item.state }}"
          loop: "{{ my_lines }}"
```

- Note 1

The structure can be simplified by adding the *state* parameter only if the line is *absent*

```yaml
    my_lines:
      - line: myfilecontent
        state: absent
      - line: mynewfilecontent
```

Declare default *state present* in the loop

```yaml
    state: "{{ item.state|default('present') }}"
```

- Note 2

The default *state*, defined in the module, is *present*. Hence, the *state* parameter may be omitted if not present in the data structure

```yaml
    state: "{{ item.state|default(omit) }}"
```

All 3 options above will do the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your line to potentially replace an existing line in the file then you need to provide a `regexp` argument to the `lineinfile` module.

> The regular expression to look for in every line of the file.
>   For state=present, the pattern to replace if found. Only the last line found will be replaced.
>   For state=absent, the pattern of the line(s) to remove.
>   If the regular expression is not matched, the line will be added to the file in keeping with insertbefore or insertafter settings.
>   When modifying a line the regexp should typically match both the initial state of the line as well as its state after replacement by line to ensure idempotence.

The last line which matches your regexp will be replaced with your `line` value; if there is no match then a new line will be added.

Without a `regexp` argument the module will just check for an exact match to your `line` value.

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html.